# Fetch record from current date to next whole month(till last date of next month) mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i.e

Suppose the current date is 18/10/2016 then i want to fetch all record from 18/10/206 to 30/11/2016

This is the scenario, please help me to get effective way to fetch this from in a single query mysql.

Comment: What do you mean by `next whole month`? Next 30 days or Next month 1-28/29/30/31?

Comment: `WHERE yourDate BETWEEN`

Comment: from current date to next month's last date, as i have explained in question with an example, you did not seen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `BETWEEN` to compare dates.

Take help of `LAST_DAY(date)` function.

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM your_table 
WHERE your_date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND LAST_DAY(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

---

**Note:**

**LAST_DAY() function**

`MySQL LAST_DAY()` returns the last day of the corresponding month for a date or datetime value. If the date or datetime value is invalid, the function returns `NULL`.

Comment: Sorry to say but this is giving a syntax error

Comment: Please share the query you tried along with the error you encountered.

Comment: This is the error : 
SQL query: Documentation


SELECT * FROM members_detail Birthdate BETWEEN CURDATE() AND LAST_DAY(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
 LIMIT 0, 25 
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BETWEEN CURDATE() AND LAST_DAY(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Comment: Sorry there are missing a where keyword, and that was of my mistake

Comment: I see you didn't use `WHERE`

Answer (score 1):

```
$time = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
$final = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 month", $time));
$nextMonth= date('t/m/Y',strtotime($final));
$now=date('d/m/Y');
$sql="select * from table where date>='".$now.' and date<=$nextMonth";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: First priority was to use only mysql if possible, otherwise we can use php, but thanks buddy :)